# a kill switch to this password checking program

Tags: python-3.x

Wrote this simple python code to check for a password. I'm trying to add a kill command but can't seem to figure it out.

```
correct_password = "python123"
password = input("Enter Password: ")
while correct_password != password:
    password = input("Try again: ")
    if password = "q":
        exit()
```

Comment: change `=` to `==` `if password = "q":` to `if password == "q":`

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use to = signs like this
if VARIABLE == yes

```
    correct_password = "python123"
password = input("Enter Password: ")
while correct_password != password:
    password = input("Try again: ")
    if password == "q":
        exit()
```

this is your code without the error.

Comment: Hey Tacoca, glad to see you give it your first attempt on answering a question. You answer is correct, although it is not very clear. By example, OP might not know which equal sign you mean, especially without explaining the difference. Try rewriting OP's code without the error, by example writting `password == "q"`. Also format your code by selecting it an clicking on "code block" so it is clear what is text and what is code